# Sequelize getting JSON string instead of JSON Object when included as an association

Tags: sequelize.js

When I find the Model directly. I get the response as a JSON object. Which is exactly how I need it.

Filter.findOne({})

```
    {
     id: 23,
     timer: {"time":"betweenMinutesXandY","from":0,"to":70,"minute":70}
    }
```

But when using as an include the timer field is JSON string:
User.findOne({include: [Filter]})

```
    {
     user: 1,
     Filter: {
      id: 23,
      timer: '{"time":"betweenMinutesXandY","from":0,"to":70,"minute":70}'
     }
    }
```

I would like to return the result in this format.

```
    
    {
     user: 1,
     Filter: {
      id: 23,
      timer: {"time":"betweenMinutesXandY","from":0,"to":70,"minute":70}
     }
    }
```

I am using MariaDB and dialect: 'mariadb'

Comment: Hey Vishal, did you find a solution for this? I have exactly the same problem

Comment: Same problem here. Did you find a solution?